# Can you make rainbow dye in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I've been looking for it, but I can't find it. Could somebody help me?

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye

Answer (score 13):

Rainbow dye is made in the Dye Vat.  You need to combine Yellow gradient, Cyan gradient and Violet gradient dye.

Here are the dyes you need to make the different gradients:

- Yellow: yellow dye, orange dye, and lime dye.
- Cyan: cyan dye, sky blue dye, and teal dye.
- Violet: violet dye, pink dye, and purple dye.

Intense Rainbow Dye is made by combing two regular Rainbow Dyes in the vat.

Check out the [Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye) for more details.